# jquery dropdown checklist plugin documentation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement a [dropdown checklist](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html), unfortunately I just can't find enough documentation for implementation. 
Has anybody used this plug-in before?, and if so, do you know of any site with the proper information for it's use?

Comment: Can you ask a specific question - ie what are you struggling with about the implementation. The plugin looks straight forward to use.

Comment: Well, more specifically, the app is not using the css that comes for it. None of the formatting is being considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this particular case (as with many plugins) the demo page is your documentation. There are many examples provided, and the source-code is readily-visible. What are you having problems with?

The author of the plugin also has [a blog](http://aleris.wordpress.com/tag/dropdown-check-list/), where you could get further support.